# rename every key of the json in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json like this:

```
 const mycontacts = [
       {
          "fleet_name":"RancorService",
          "owner":"swapneil",
          "host_count":10,
          "environment":"RancorService/JP",
          "vip_name":"rancor-02.pdx.amazon.com",
          "region":"pdx",
          "lb_set":"pdx-internal-111-set",
          "alternatename":"RANCOR-02-PDX-80",
          "protocol":"HTTP",
          "viptag":"retail_general",
          "port":80,
          "lb_status":"NOT_DEDICATED_VIP",
          "current_req_per_sec":0.9495412127,
          "current_req_res_per_gb_per_sec_payload":0.0309901519,
          "req_per_sec_threshold":80,
          "req_res_per_gb_sec_threshold":4,
          "partition_proposed":"NO"

    },
       {
          "fleet_name":"RancorService",
          "owner":"swapneil",
          "host_count":11,
          "environment":"RancorService/JP",
          "vip_name":"rancor-01.pdx.amazon.com",
          "region":"pdx",
          "lb_set":"pdx-internal-57-set",
          "alternatename":"RANCOR-01-PDX-80",
          "protocol":"HTTP",
          "viptag":"retail_general",
          "port":80,
          "lb_status":"NOT_DEDICATED_VIP",
          "current_req_per_sec":0.927976804,
          "current_req_res_per_gb_per_sec_payload":0.030198045,
          "req_per_sec_threshold":80,
          "req_res_per_gb_sec_threshold":4,
          "partition_proposed":"NO"

    }
]
```

I want to rename all the keys as the following but the values of the keys should not change.

```
const changedkeys = { 'Fleet name', 'Owner', 'Host Count', 'Environment', 'Vip Name', 'Region', 'LBset', 'Alternate Name', 'Protocol', 'Vip tag', 'Port', 'LB status', 'Current Requirement(/sec)', 'Current Request Response Payload(/gb/sec)', 'Request Threshold(/sec)', 'Request Response Threshold(/gb/sec)', 'Partition Proposed' }
```

Only the key name is to be replaced with the new keys but the values of the keys should not change. How to achieve that??

Comment: i have tried simple assignment of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the renamed keys are mapped in orders, try using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to generate the desired array of objects:

```js
const mycontacts = [
    {
        "fleet_name": "RancorService",
        "owner": "swapneil",
        "host_count": 10,
        "environment": "RancorService/JP",
        "vip_name": "rancor-02.pdx.amazon.com",
        "region": "pdx",
        "lb_set": "pdx-internal-111-set",
        "alternatename": "RANCOR-02-PDX-80",
        "protocol": "HTTP",
        "viptag": "retail_general",
        "port": 80,
        "lb_status": "NOT_DEDICATED_VIP",
        "current_req_per_sec": 0.9495412127,
        "current_req_res_per_gb_per_sec_payload": 0.0309901519,
        "req_per_sec_threshold": 80,
        "req_res_per_gb_sec_threshold": 4,
        "partition_proposed": "NO"

    },
    {
        "fleet_name": "RancorService",
        "owner": "swapneil",
        "host_count": 11,
        "environment": "RancorService/JP",
        "vip_name": "rancor-01.pdx.amazon.com",
        "region": "pdx",
        "lb_set": "pdx-internal-57-set",
        "alternatename": "RANCOR-01-PDX-80",
        "protocol": "HTTP",
        "viptag": "retail_general",
        "port": 80,
        "lb_status": "NOT_DEDICATED_VIP",
        "current_req_per_sec": 0.927976804,
        "current_req_res_per_gb_per_sec_payload": 0.030198045,
        "req_per_sec_threshold": 80,
        "req_res_per_gb_sec_threshold": 4,
        "partition_proposed": "NO"

    }
];

const changedkeys = ['Fleet name', 'Owner', 'Host Count', 'Environment', 'Vip Name', 'Region', 'LBset', 'Alternate Name', 'Protocol', 'Vip tag', 'Port', 'LB status', 'Current Requirement(/sec)', 'Current Request Response Payload(/gb/sec)', 'Request Threshold(/sec)', 'Request Response Threshold(/gb/sec)', 'Partition Proposed'];

const newArray = mycontacts.map(contact => Object.fromEntries(Object.values(contact).map((v, i) => [changedkeys[i], v])));

console.log(newArray);
```